# Protobuf: how nested (custom) optional fields are to be handled in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Reading into [Protocol Buffer Basics: C++](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial), found nothing that matches the situation:; with following *.proto* processed with `--cpp_out`,

```
message A {
 required int32 foo = 1;
}
message B {
 optional A data = 1;
}
```

no obviously looking accessor/setter is generated to set custom optional field (including 'nested types' section which I'm too lazy to put here):

```
   // accessors -------------------------------------------------------

   // optional .A = 1;
   inline bool has_a() const;
   inline void clear_a();
   static const int kAFieldNumber = 1;
   inline const ::A& a() const;
   inline ::A* mutable_a();
   inline ::A* release_a();
```

So, **how to set B::A to some A instance in C++?**

---

**TEST FILES**: [.proto](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?3d66cy6gjs27), generated results: [.h](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?xpwqyvusf210), [.cc](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?6ubwc0wlatct) and some [.java](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?3iz27edjj8l8)

---

Upd: in Java, nested fields are set via Builder: see link above for example (look for *setData*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution: use mutable to modify some returned doodad.

```
A a;
A.set_foo(1);

B b;
B.mutable_A()->CopyFrom(a);
```